# Javascript/jQuery based dynamic list with indentation

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I'm build the UI for a web-based list app.

Does anyone know of a script that allows users to arrange the ordering of html elements?
similar to this
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ but also has the ability to indent items by dragging horizontally? (to represent parent child relationships)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the parent-child relationship you want creates a tree, so why not looking for some jQuery Tree plugins that allow drag and drop.

I found this after a quick search in google:
http://www.jstree.com/demo

There are several Tree plugins that do something similar to what you want.